# Core Animation image change in IKImageView?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, imagekit

Is there any way to animate (using one of the supplied Core Animations) an image change in IKImageView without resorting to using two independent IKImageViews upon a new image load?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for that. You can only add core animation overlay/background to IKImageView.